# Excel Chart Zoom-Out Function

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2003, vba

I already coded a Zoom-In Function for Charts in Excel, but I dont know how to do the Zoom-Out with the Scrollbar Value.

Can anybody help me?

```
Private Sub Zoom_X_Change1()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 20").Chart

        If (.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale >= 0) And (.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale < 0.4) Then
                .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale + 0.1
        End If

        If (.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale > 0.6) And (.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale <= 1) Then
                .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale - 0.1
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Scroll:

```
Dim aX As Integer
Dim aY As Integer
Dim arrScale As Variant

Private Sub Scale_X_Change()
    arrScale = Array(-0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11)
    aX = arrScale(Scale_X.Value - 1)
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 20").Chart
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = aX
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is this code connected to a spin button or some other form control?

Comment: @DavidZemens: It's a Scrollbar

Comment: Is the scrollbar linked to a cell?

Comment: @DavidZemens It's linked to a Chart

Comment: No it's not. Right click the scroll bar and do "Format Control", is there a value for Cell Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Make sure the ScrollBar is linked to a cell, in my example it is `J5` but modify that as needed.

This macro will compare the current axis `.MinimumScale` to the value of the linked cell, and will zoom in and out.

[image: Format control to a linked cell]

Also make sure that the min/max and incremental values for the ScrollBar are set accordingly, for example:

[image: Set the scroll bar properties]

```
Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
Dim ax As Axis
Dim sbMin As Double
Dim sbMax As Double
Dim sbMove As Double
Dim sbVal As Double
Dim minVal As Double
Dim maxVal As Double

sbMin = 0   '## Set this to the minimum desired axis scale.'
sbMax = 0.6 '## set this to the maximum desired axis scale.'
sbMove = 0.1 '## Set this to the desired increment.'
sbVal = Range("J5").Value '## this is the cell linked to the scrollbar, modify as needed.'

Set ax = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 20").Chart.Axes(xlCategory)

    With ax
        '## check to see if we are zooming out, and flip the sign on sbMove'
        If sbVal < .MinimumScale Then sbMove = sbMove * -1
        '## Manipulate the axis min & max:'
        If Not sbVal >= 0.5 * sbMax Then
        '## Manipulate the axis min & max:'
            If (.MinimumScale <> sbVal) Then
                .MinimumScale = .MinimumScale + sbMove
                .MaximumScale = .MaximumScale - sbMove
                .CrossesAt = sbVal
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it's working pretty good (the min, max steps are a little bit tricky but ok) but my Y-Axis is now jumping/moving to the right side. Do you know a fix for it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: I fixed the problem (the incremental change was the problem) but I found another "bug". Im Starting from 0 to 10, he zooms in, I can also Zoom out but the Scaling of the X-Axis doesnt work/isnt right after that.
Screenshot: http://abload.de/img/prob1zrdwi.png

Comment: set the ScrollBar's "Maximum Value" to 1/2 of the X-Axis `.MaximumScale` value, e.g., if the original X-Axis goes to .6, set the scroll bar maximum = .3.  Then try revised code, above.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: Thank you, its working pretty good so far :) Last question:  Do you have an Idea how to improbe the scroll function without arrays etc.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, there are no arrays in this function.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post it David. I just edited my question above.

Comment: @mrks that looks like a new question. Your new question is "How can I improve the function without arrays", which doesn't make sense, because the answer I propose does not use array variables in the first place. Please consider posting it as a new question to avoid extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: Hm okay but you helped me already with my zoom-in/zoom-out question. Do you know how I just can simply "scroll" the x-Axis via a scrollbar? My solution is very buggy and not clean, so it would be great if you could help me with this last question! :-)

Comment: If you post a new question, you have a **much** better chance that someone will be able to answer it and help you out.  Also, it is proper etiquette/forum rules to do so, instead of dragging this out in extended comments. I will not be replying to this comment thread anymore. If you want help, please post it as a new question.